# i'm not able to redirect page from another page using nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
function skipBR() {
    location.href = 'boardroom.ejs';
    
}
```

here I want to call boardroom.ejs file in different page using function.

Comment: please help me out of this.

Comment: There is no window object in nodejs. That is available only in the browser so location.href doest work. You need to use res.redirect("/<your route path>") to achieve redirection

Answer (score 0):

The `location.href = '/path'` is a client side function, in server side is used the `Express` function `res.redirect('/path')` as @santhosh has mentioned in the comments.

This would look something like:

**terminal:**

```
npm install -s express
```

**your .js file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => 
    res.redirect('/boardroom.ejs');
});
```